# Typescript React Lazy load components in route

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i am trying to lazy load a component like this:

```
const NewPost = React.lazy(() => import('./NewPost/NewPost'));
```

And then i want to load it inside a route like this:

```
<Route 
    path="/new-post" 
    render={() => (
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
            <NewPost />
        </Suspense>
    )} 
/>
```

And my NewPost is defined like this:

```
interface INewPostProps extends RouteComponentProps<any> {}

interface INewPostState {
  title: string;
}

class NewPost extends React.Component<INewPostProps, INewPostState> {
```

But i get this error:

Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'INewPostProps'.
  Property 'history' is missing in type '{}'.

Which refers to this line:
 inside Route => Suspense.

What am i missing ?

PS: I stackoverflow the best place to ask/find info regarding typescript / react ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `NewPost` React Component requires the properties from `RouteComponentProps`, but you aren't setting them when you render `<NewPost />`

The route `render` method receives props that you're ignoring, you can re-write like this:

```js
<Route
  path="/new-post"
  render={(props) => (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <NewPost {...props} />
    </Suspense>
  )}
/>
```

Recall that the Route `render` method takes a `React.SFC`, which is your anonymous arrow function, which receives props injected by react-router

The `props` variable here will be typed as `RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>`, so you can spread them onto your `NewPost` instance to satisfy it's prop constraints